# Unable to load Nodes table in Cytoscape from csv

Tags: graph, cytoscape

I try to load a Node table from CSV (File -> Import -> Table from File) into an empty Network, in Cytoscape Version 3.8.0, Java 11.0.7 by Ubuntu.

The problem is that I don't get anything in 'Node table' (right bottom corner - only the attributes are visible). 
I try to load :

name, node_type
ind01, user
ind02, user
ind03, article
ind04, article
ind05, user
ind06, user

[Loading from csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/453hs.png)

But get the empty Node table

[Empty Node table at right bottom corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPpzV.png)

Any help would be appreciated,
Thank you.

Comment: Just to elaborate on this, when I try to import (File -> Import -> Network from File) and provide a CSV containing a table with edges, then the edges and nodes are successfully imported into Cytoscape. 

I just want to import only Nodes and their attributes (and then eventually Edges) but it seems not possible.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible, but a bit confusing.  What you actually need to do is to use File->Import->Network from File, even if you have no edges.  Just select only the Source and don't select a target and then make all of the attributes Source Node attributes.  Cytoscape makes a distinction between "Tables" and "Networks".  Tables (e.g. Node Table and Edge Table) are always attached to a network, so if you have an empty network, there is nothing for the rows of the table to attach to, hence you get empty rows.   So, the workaround is to import your table as a network, with no edges, and you should be able to get what you want.  Note that when you try to import your edges later, you'll have a bit of a challenge -- you'll actually need to import your edges as a separate network and then use Network Merge.

Comment: Got error "The network cannot be created wihout selecting the source and target columns"